# Enviar e-mail com vários anexos

Tags: delphi, envio-de-email, indy-10

Estou enviando e-mail através do INDY, o e-mail está sendo enviado e o anexo está indo, porém como consta no código abaixo, eu faço um for pra percorrer todos os anexos, e ele só envia o último, alguém sabe o que está errado?

```
    if pAnexo.Count > 0 then
    begin
      for i := 0 to pAnexo.Count - 1 do
      begin
          vIdAttachmentFile.Create(vIdMessage.MessageParts, pAnexo.Strings[i]);
      end;
    end;
```

A variável **pAnexo** é um vetor onde constam os arquivos que irão em anexo, estou tentando enviar um jpeg e um xml, futuramente quero enviar um PDF junto.

Comment: estou olhando um exemplo que funciona, a diferença que vi, é que ao invés de uma variável está direto da classe assim: `TIdAttachmentFile.Create`...

Comment: Bah, muito obrigada! Funcionou assim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abaixo segue a maneira que deu certo para mim, era só um detalhe! Melissa me ajudou: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/111325/melissa

```
if pAnexo.Count > 0 then
begin
  for i := 0 to pAnexo.Count - 1 do
  begin
      TIdAttachmentFile.Create(vIdMessage.MessageParts, pAnexo[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o `pAnexo` seja um `stringList`, senão for, altere. E então passe dessa forma:

```
vIdAttachmentFile.Create(vIdMessage.MessageParts, pAnexo[i]);
```

Outra coisa, verifique o `ContentType`:

```
vIdMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
```

Comment: Não funcionou assim, continua enviando só o último arquivo

Comment: que pena :/ não consigo testar no momento :/